# What exactly is kept alive in Alive TCP Connection?

Tags: http, networking, tcp, udp, communication

Please bear the naivity of this question as I have close to no knowledge of networking. Please help me understand this thing more clearly.
Suppose, there is a river and people from both the ends needs to travel back and forth from one end to another. So a bridge can act as connection between both ends, Till the time, bridge is alive, The connection is said to be alive and travelling is possible. I want to know what does it mean to keep a TCP connection alive and what is exactly kept alive? As in case of river, bridge was kept alive.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to a bridge a TCP connection is not a physical thing but only a logical association between to ends. Data get delivered between the ends hop by hop through several intermediate systems. Single packets might get lost on the way or even the other end or some intermediate systems might crash so that connectivity is lost completely.

As long as regular data exchange is done between the ends such conditions can quickly be detected. If one end sends data the other has to acknowledge these - if the acknowledgement is missing the packet gets retransmitted. If data are still not acknowledged after retransmissions the connection is considered broken.

But the ends might not continuously exchange data. If the connection is idle (i.e. no data exchange) then it will not be detected that something got broken. TCP keep alive works around this problem by regularly exchanging packets on idle connections and expecting an acknowledgment. These are packets with no data payload since no data are there to be transmitted.

Comment: Okay, I got your point that connection is kept alive by sending messages at regular interval. But what is the difference between sending packets while connections is there and making a connection. After all making connection must also involve sending packets. Is it like, after making a connection a well-defined route is decided and further communication will happen on that predefined route, something like that.

Comment: @GauravKandoria: *"that connection is kept alive by sending messages at regular interval."* - This is not about keeping the connection alive but checking the connection is still alive. Keeping the states in intermediate stateful firewalls or NAT is an intended side effect though. And making a new connection is like building a new bridge, not rebuilding exactly the same one again. Cars waiting on the old bridge will not automatically use the new one since it starts at a different local port.

Answer (score 0):

In both these end-points, some data (or state variables) needs to be associated with each connection which is necessary to execute TCP protocol. E.g., sender needs to remember sequence numbers, maintain copies of all sent/but not acknowledged packets. Receiver needs to track sequence numbers too, store copies of packets that are out of order, and reconstruct original stream from received packets. These state data structures are created (i.e., memory is allocated) when the connection is established, and are destroyed (memory is freed) when the connection is terminated (e.g., after exchanging FINs). This state is accociated with each open TCP socket. A good practice is not to have connections open forever without exchanging data (e.g., if one of the communication partners has crashed, it won't be able to do proper connection termination), so if the connection is idle for a long period (which i don't know exactly) it is reasonable that the socket is closed. The concept is known as "soft state", which basically means that each state (memory) has an expiration inactivity time untill it is deleted. If the socket is closed, then when new data has to be sent, new connection has to be established. Yes it does involve sending packets, but it has overhead of sending TCP packets without any payload for one RTT, before the first data is sent.

In theory TCP connection exists only on end-points of the connection. In practice, however, there are also many kinds of so called "middleboxes", which is a general name for network device that is not a router or a switch. These middleboxes sometimes also need to maintain state accociated with each TCP connections, so these keepalives will also refresh the state on these middleboxes.

But in both cases, these keepalives basically tell to reset inactivity timer associate with state for this connection.